# Color.Transparent is black only on Samsung device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-color

I set the code in `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
var rootView = FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView;
rootView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

How to make it truly transparent?

Comment: You can set  `Transparent` Background by set opacity .Check https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-transparent-background-by-set-opacity-3a36ef615e1d

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#00FFFFFF")); It didn't help, the same black background

Comment: What are you expecting the color to be if your app has a transparent background?  You're at the mercy of whatever the device is displaying just behind your app, which apparently is black.

Comment: Black part of the screen during 1 sec after keyboard is hidden, so I fixed it on other devices using transparent